Amenability of locally convex algebras
Let $A$ be an amenable Banach algebra, and let $A_w$ denote $A$ with the weak topology. Clearly, $A_w$ is a Hausdorff locally convex algebra (l.c.a.).

Q0: Is $A_w$ amenable as a l.c.a. in the sense of [Helemskii1993]?

Perhaps the converse holds.

Q1: If $B$ is an amenable l.c.a., is $c_0(B)$ also an amenable l.c.a.?

where $c_0(B) = \lbrace (b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}: b_n\to 0 \textrm{ in } B  \rbrace$. If $B$ is an amenable Banach algebra, then so is $c_0(B)$.
I admit that this is a lazy question hoping to find out a well-known result if there is any. My initial guess is that both questions do not have a positive answer simultaneously.
Thanks in advance.
